# Sending form information to an email address stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

Hi what I am trying to do is to create a form that a user fills out some information,on submit that information is then sent to email addresses that they have already saved into a database.
I have created an sql statement where the user saves the persons name and email like so

```
  mysql_select_db("lr", $con);
 $sql="INSERT INTO bridesmaids (FirstName, email)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[email]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }
echo "Bridesmaid added"; 
?>
```

So in my other form I would like the information to be sent to the "email" field in this table, is this possible?

Comment: use php inbuild function for mailing,search for mail(),http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 0):

You would normally fetch emails from the database and loop over them sending them your message, http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp is a good start for sending mails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible, but you need a mail server to use in order to send emails. if you are using an online hosting service that includes emails, it should be enough to use this line of code:

```
mail("to@email.com", "message subject", "message body", "From: from@email.com");
```

if you have a separate mail server you need to specify the mail server configuration in the php.ini file.